# SQL Selecting from three tables

Tags: sql, database

I have three tables

```
Table name - Emlpoyee
Emp_id, Emp_name, Address, Area of Expertise
```

---

```
Table name - Pallocation
Emp_id, PROJECT_ID, STAFF_COST
```

---

```
Table name - Projects
PROJECT_ID, Project_name, Client
```

and I need to find out SQL queries & statement for three different questions

> Q1) Display the employee_name, Project_IDs and staff cost for all employees
>
> Q2) Change the staff cost in PALLOCATION of Kayleigh Donald in the TV ad project from 900 to 1200
>
> Q3) Include Joy Davies in the TV ad Project (P300) with cost of 800. The change has to happen in PALLOCATION table.

Comment: OK. Start writing your SQL.

Comment: [begin here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Show sample data and output what you want to achive and what database are you using?

Comment: Do your own homework! Just asking someone else is not the best way to learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1) Display the employee_name, Project_IDs and staff cost for all
>   employees

Should be like this:

```
SELECT e.Emp_name, pa.PROJECT_ID, pa.STAFF_COST
FROM Emlpoyee e
JOIN Pallocation pa 
   ON e.Emp_id = pa.Emp_id
```

Comment: they are three different questions!

Comment: You should ask 1 question per time.

Comment: I think you should ask new separate questions If you want to get answers to all of them. I answered to 1st one.

Comment: thank you! Will do and ask the rest of two questions